# Reverse polarity, over-voltage and over-current protection for a "breadboard add-on board"

Tags: circuit-protection, breadboard, over-voltage-protection, reverse-polarity, over-current

I am designing a small utility board that should attach to a breadboard and take power from it.

It can be described as the opposite of this SparkFun Breadboard Power Supply: instead of powering the board, it draws power from it.

[image: SparkFun Breadboard Power Supply]

Since it's not possible to know for sure what source is powering the board, it would be nice to implement some protection. I am now thinking of these possible scenarios:

1. The polarity of the power source is reversed, it's easy to make such mistake since the breadboard is symmetric
2. The input voltage is too high: I am planning to use an LDO with 15V maximum input voltage, and it's unlikely that someone is applying a voltage higher than this to a breadboard, but still plausible
3. Some electrical connection on the board is shorted with a small conductive object or the board is somehow connected in such a way that the current flows through it

Are there any other scenarios against which the protection might be required that I didn't think of?

Ideally, the protection circuit should have some indicator (for example, a flashing LED) that would show to the user that the protection was triggered, and this is why the rest of the board doesn't start up. I was thinking of using [LTC4361](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc4361.html), it seems to have all the required functions. Is it a good choice? How should it be connected to implement protection against all plausible incorrect connection scenarios?